# Tornado MySQLDB SSL Connection

Tags: python, ssl, tornado, mysql-python

I’m using tornado and connecting to MySQL using MySQLDB. How I can connect to MySQL using SSL?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do that an SSL connection is required? It will slow down your database queries

Comment: The DB contains sensitive information. Hence we want to use secure channel for communication.

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL server is on the same host as the web server then you don't really need to do this since traffic will not leave that box. You can use an ssh tunnel to encrypt traffic if you'd like. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
$ ssh <mysql_port>:localhost:<mysql_port> user@mysqlserver.host
```

That will create a tunnel from your MySQL server to the web server. You can then connect to `localhost:port` instead of `mysqlserver.host:port`.